# Module is not working correctly with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I can't use functions that are in another module in my main module

```
#MAIN FILE - mainfile.py

#Imports / display / pygame.init

from file2 import *

font=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",35)

example(1) #THERE I DEFINE DE CLASS

Text=font.render(list1[0],0,(255,255,255))
win.blit(Text,(5,5))


#while loop
```

```
#file 2 - file2.py


class example:
    def __init__(self, whichlist):
        global list1
        if whichlist==1:
            list1=["bird", "bird2", "bird3"]
        elif whichlist==2:
            list1=["bird", "bird2", "bird3"]
        
        #more code
```

## I know that I can just define the example class in the file2, but I want to define it in the main file.

Comment: What exactly is the issue with just putting it there?

Comment: How I can define the class in the main file without getting an error, I'm talking about the example(1)

Comment: Can you explain in details what "an error" is?

Comment: to **define** in file1 you would have to copy code from file2 to file2. But probably you rather means "how to **use** class, from other file". But in your example `function` seems better then `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `function` could be better then `class`. And instead of `global` better use `return`.

In `file2.py`

```
def get_list(whichlist)
    if whichlist == 1:
       return ["bird", "bird2", "bird3"]
    elif whichlist == 2:
       return ["bird", "bird2", "bird3"]
    #else:
    #   return []
```

In `file1.py`

```
from file2 import get_list

list1 = get_list(1)
```

---

If you really need to use class then you should create method in class which uses `return`

There is also good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - it means `Example` instead of `example

In `file2.py`

```
class Example:

    def get_list(self, whichlist):
        if whichlist == 1:
            return ["bird", "bird2", "bird3"]
        elif whichlist == 2:
            return ["bird", "bird2", "bird3"]
        #else:
        #    return []
```

In `file1.py`

```
from file2 import Example

ex = Example()
list1 = ex.get_list(1)
```

Eventually

```
list1 = Example().get_list(1)
```